# Can't kill a python process in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I've searched in a lot of places but I can't seem to get the keywords correct. I have a stalling process in Python in Sublime that causes the beachball of death on a Mac. I can't access the Tools > Cancel Build button and Control + C doesn't work. How do I kill this process?

Comment: While you find the solution, you can add in a syntax error and run the program again so it stops automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have not found a way to kill a process in Sublime without killing all of Sublime.  But I did find a way to make killing and reopening Sublime much less painful. Here is my way.

1. Command-option-escape:  This brings up the force-quit window.
2. The force-quit window will ask you if you really want to quit Sublime twice. Just hit enter twice.
3. A crash reporter window will open. I hated this window, because it floats on top of everything so you can't ignore it, and closing it made me do extra keystrokes, so I [disabled it.](http://www.yourdailymac.net/2012/02/how-to-disable-the-mac-os-x-crash-reporter-snow-leopard-lion/)
4. Reopen sublime.  When Sublime re-opens, it opens all of the files you had open before it crashed, taking you back to where you were.

Many people think reopening Sublime is pain in the butt because they have to navigate to the Applications Directory with their mouse, a process which takes about 10 - 30 seconds. I used to find this annoying, so I set it up so that I could reopen sublime with five keystrokes, and it takes me about three seconds.

First, I installed [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/).  In this case, you only need the free version of Alfred.

With Alfred installed, do the following:

1. option-spacebar brings up the Alfred search bar.  Alfred is a lot like Google Search for your computer.
2. Type the letters "su."  Below the Alfred search bar, a bunch of options appear, and the first option is Sublime Text 2. Alfred automatically highlights the first thing on it's list of search results, so that when you hit enter, it will launch the highlighted application.
3. Hit enter.  Alfred opens Sublime.  Voila: Sublime is back to how it was before you ran the script.

So, in total, once I start a process that freezes Sublime, I do the following 10 keystrokes:

Cmd-option-escape enter enter  option-spacebar s u enter

This procedure does leave the Force Quit Applications window hanging around, because I have not found a quick way to get rid of it without adding ten extra keystrokes to my system. If it really bugs me, I click on the window and do cmd-w, which closes the window.

The other annoying thing is that it takes a couple of seconds for Sublime to relaunch, so usually I don't bother to run things from within Sublime. Instead, I go over to the terminal and run things there, so that I can Ctrl-C the script I'm testing without affecting Sublime.

Additionally, there is a keyboard shortcut for the Tools > Cancel Build option.  I have never used it, but using it and fixing problems with it is discussed in [this forum post.](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4765)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response though I was hoping for something similar to what control+c does in the terminal. At least I'm not alone in thinking that this is a problem.

Comment: I keep 'Force Quit Applications' open in the bottom-right of the display. It removes one step (command-escape) from Tara's solution, and rarely is there any code in the bottom right most corner of Sublime.

Answer (score 6):

**This answer is specific to python and windows.** I am not sure if there is a mac equivalent.

A running python script can be terminated from the **task manager**. Use `Ctrl+Shift+esc` to open the Task Manager. Go to the `processes` tab and kill `python.exe` by simply pessing `del`. This would only terminate the script and leave sublime untouched.

Comment: For OS X, you can go to Activity Monitor and find the process "python" and force quit that process. Mind you, doing that will kill all python processes I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I found an interesting way to solve this.

My build system on sublime-text2 call my Makefile which has 2 options and uses the ONESHELL directive:

```
.ONESHELL:
run: myprogram
    ./myprogram &
    echo $$! > "pid.tmp"
```

Note that after it starts my program its pid is saved on a file.
And i have a second option:

```
stop:
    kill -9 `cat pid.tmp`
    rm pid.tmp
```

This option kills the process started by the `run` command.

Then i configured my build system (Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...) so i could access both options:

```
{
    "cmd": ["make"],
    "variants":
    [
            {
                    "name": "Run",
                    "cmd": ["make", "run"]
            },
            {
                    "name": "Stop",
                    "cmd": ["make", "stop"]
            }
    ]
```

}

But i want to call both options from key bindings on sublime so i edited the file "Preferences -> Key Bindings - User" to look like this:

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+r"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "Run"} },
{ "keys": ["alt+r"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "Stop"} }
]
```

Now if i press ctrl+r my program starts (and enters an infinity loop) and when i press alt+r my program stops which is almost what i wanted.

The only problem left is that when i run alt+r i loose the output produced by ctrl+r.

Edit:
Other way i found was to start my program on a new xterm process on the Makefile:

```
run:
    xterm ./myprogram
```

I can close it with ctrl+c and it wont stop sublime from working.

Answer (score 1):

I have "ported" VGarcia's solution to Python. However, if you need a Makefile for your project anyway, you should probably go for the Makefile method.

**Remark on VGarcia's solution:**

- VGarcia's solution worked nice for me, but I had to write `./myprogram & echo $$! > "pid.tmp"` on a single line, otherwise the stored PID would end being empty.
- I wanted to build the binary before running so I just added a build target `myprogram` and kept the dependency `run: myprogram`

(I know this should be a comment, but I did not have enough reputation for that. I will make it a comment when I can.)

**Python version**

Write a run.py script that runs the program and stores the PID of the process (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
from subprocess import Popen  # prefer subprocess32 in Python 2 for Linux / OS X

# run process as child (still receive process output)
pid = Popen(['build/myprogram']).pid

# store pid
with open('pid.tmp', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(pid))
```

Write a stop.py script to read the PID and kill the process:

```
import os, signal
from subprocess import Popen

# read PID
with open('pid.tmp', 'r') as f:
    pid = f.readline().rstrip()

# kill process
os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)

# remove temp file
os.remove('pid.tmp')
```

Configure the build:

```
{
    "name": "Python Build",
    // adapt for your project
    "cmd": [my_build_cmd],
    "working_dir": "$project_path",
    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["python", "run.py"], 
        },
        {
             "name": "Stop",
             "cmd": ["python", "stop.py"],
        }
    ]
}
```

Or you can put all the functions in one module and call the different methods `run`and `stop` by parsing some arguments in `main()`.

**Improvement suggestion 1** (not tried myself)

You may want to reuse your scripts for different projects. In this case:

1. Change your scripts into functions with parameters. You will probably want at least `def run(bin_path)`. Put the script(s) somewhere you can easily access from any project.
2. In your sublime-project, put the build configuration in the `build_systems` entry (the value is a list, see https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html, a bit old but usable). You can either call the functions directly with `"cmd": ["python", "-c", "from script import run; run(bin_path)"]` or use `main()` as suggested above.

**Improvement suggestion 2** (not tried myself)

If you run the program through multiple processes at once (accidentally, or to test some networking feature), the `stop` procedure will only kill the last process. You can adapt the algorithm to store multiple PIDs in the temp file, then kill each process accordingly.

You can also do this with the Makefile method as a shell script. In any case, be sure to pick a language you feel at ease with.

Answer (score 0):

Launch task manager or whatever process manager you have on your computer (if you don't, get one). Delete the corresponding python.exe and pythonw.exe process

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just needed to handle the SIGTERM signal in my program coming from Sublime Text.

```
import sys, signal

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
```

There is also a bug related to this, if you start new build when the old one is still running, it only terminates the process when you print something to terminal: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1049

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers on this page actually worked for me.
The sad truth seems to be that there are no "*civilized*" way of killing a python script started on sublime (<kbd>CTRL/COMMAND + B</kbd>).

Answer (score -1):

If you are a mac or linux user, you can kill all python processes by `killall` command.

```sh
killall -9 Python
```

**Quick Access**

You may later add as an alias to the bash_profile script and run the same code by calling `killpython`.

```sh
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this line as alias.

```sh
alias killpython='killall -9 Python; echo "killed all snakes ";
```

Save it and reload the script.

```sh
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Done.

Answer (score -2):

In SublimeText3, there is a keyboard shortcut for Tools > Cancel Build: `^C`. If you click down in the build log and then enter control+C, it will stop the build with the message `[Cancelled]`.

Comment: The program will not stop, I tried it :(((. look at Task Manager