# How to stop an infinite loop in a sublime text build

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Running a ruby script in Sublime 2 I'm in an infinite loop. Is there an equivalent of bash ctrl-c that will force stop the script without closing the application? All controls in the window seem unresponsive.

Comment: [According to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759518/cant-kill-a-python-process-in-sublime-text-2) you'll need to kill Sublime.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that post. That's the best I've come up with so far as well.

Comment: Theoretically, going to `Tools -> Cancel Build` should work. If you're on Linux or OS X you should be able to run `ps x` from the command line, and see if there's a process you can kill (such as `ruby` itself) without bringing down the whole program, but that may not work. One good thing to keep in mind is that Sublime is pretty fault-tolerant, so you shouldn't lose any work you haven't saved, even if the process does need to be killed externally.

Comment: I always kill sublime process to stop it. (I try to use hot-save in preference). Is it bad way?

Answer (score 5):

In Sublime Text 3 they have Cancel Build. Not sure if 2 has it but if it does try that under tools. Ctrl-C in ST3.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to catch it before Sublime locks keyboard input. Gonna try to go to the toolbar I guess

Answer (score 2):

On a UNIX machine:

```
$killall "ruby"
```

did the trick for me, given you don't run any other ruby script in the mean time.